# Get block of size bytes of memory

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, llvm

Suppose I have this code:

```
struct S {
  int* a;
  float b;
};

struct S foo(void) {
  s.a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
  s.b = 2;

  return s;
}

int main() {
  struct S s = foo();

  // Parse the code here

  return 0;
}
```

By using `LLVM` is it possible to get the number of bytes allocated by the malloc by only using the `llvm::Type` on `s.a` in the `main` function? I know that it is possible to get the size of the pointer, in bits and bytes, but not the total size. I'm actually using the `bitcode` (`.bc` file) in order to get the `llvm::Type`.

Comment: What is the 'total size'... If the struct resides on the stack, one pointer points to a value in the data segment and another pointer points to malloced value on the heap there is no block of size x. You could only get a count of bytes totally used.
To get the size of your pointer s.a, someone has to ask the internal malloc structs. Only these structs know the size of the allocated block.

Comment: `struct S foo(void) {
  s.a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
  s.b = 2;

  return s;}`  There is no `s` : s is undefined. (and  `llvm::Type` is a syntax error in C)